# How to understand this DAG of textFile and reduceByKey

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I write a simple word cound code as follows:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
rdd = sc.textFile("data/words.txt")
rdd1 = rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(", "))
rdd2 = rdd1.map(lambda x: (x, 1))
rdd2.cache()
rdd3 = rdd2.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)
print(rdd3.collect())
rdd2.unpersist()
time.sleep(1111111)
```

Following is the DAG of Stage 0 and my questions are:

1. The "textFile" comprises 2 steps in the top blue block.. Why and what are they.
2. In the codes, before rdd2 get cached, it should be processed by `flatmap` and `map`, where are they?
3. `reduceByKey` comprises 2 steps, what are they and why are they not in the same blue block?

Thanks for your help in advance.

[image]